# Allow modification of only non-zero elements of a sparse matrix

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sparse-matrix

I am implementing a tridiagonal matrix and I have to be as efficient as possible. Obviously I will only hold the elements that contain data. I overloaded the `operator()` to act as an indexer into the matrix, but I want this operator to return a reference so that the user can modify the matrix. However, I cannot just `return 0;` for the non-tridiagonal elements since the zero is not a reference. How do I let the user modify the data on the tridiagonal, but when the `operator()` is used to inspect a non-tridiagonal element, only return 0 instead of a reference to 0?

below is the related class definition

```
template <class T>
class tridiagonal
{
  public:
    tridiagonal();
    ~tridiagonal();
    T& operator()(int i, int j);
    const T& operator()(int i, int j) const; 

  private:
    //holds data of just the diagonals
    T * m_upper;
    T * m_main;
    T * m_lower;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have here is an inappropriate interface. If your definition of a matrix is a 2D array of numbers such that every element of the matrix can be individually set, then a sparse, tridiagional matrix is paradoxically *not* a matrix (just as a square is not a *modifiable* rectangle - a classic example of inappropriate inheritance that doesn't obey the Liskov Substitution Principle).

In short, you'd be better off changing your interface to suit sparse, tridiagonal matrices rather than trying to hack it to work with the interface you've got. That said, if you must do it this way, then you are probably better off doing two things:

- Modifying your `const` accessor to return `T` instead of `const T&` (I'm assuming we're only dealing with matrices of numbers here). Then you can just return `0` for the elements off the diagonal.
- Modifying your non-`const` accessor to return a reference to a dummy element for locations off the diagonal, and crossing your fingers :) Alternatively, you could change the specification to `throw` in such cases, but that might be a little unfriendly.

One other alternative (short of reworking the interface properly) might be to return proxy objects instead of `T`s. The proxy for dummy elements would then `throw` when you try and set the value using it.

Comment: I have chosen to throw when someone attempts to modify a non-diagonal element. It is indeed messy, but the assignment requires the interface to be as it is. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use is to have the non-const operator() (int, int) method return a little helper object. The helper is used to differentiate between assigning into the matrix and just pulling out a value. This lets you have different behavior for the two operations. In particular, you can throw if someone tries to assign into a value that must be zero.

This code at least compiles for me in VC10, but obviously doesn't link.

```
template <class T>
class tridiagonal
{
  public:

    // Helper class that let's us tell when the user is
    // assigning into the matrix and when they are just
    // getting values.
    class helper
    {
        tridiagonal<T> &m_parent;

        int m_i, m_j;

    public:
        helper(tridiagonal<T> &parent, int i, int j)
            : m_parent(parent), m_i(i), m_j(j)
        {}

        // Converts the helper class to the underlying
        // matrix value. This doesn't allow assignment.
        operator const T & () const {
            // Just call the const operator() 
            const tridiagonal<T> &constParent = m_parent;

            return constParent(m_i, m_j);
        }

        // Assign a value into the matrix.
        // This is only called for assignment.
        const T & operator= (const T &newVal) {
            // If we are pointing off the diagonal, throw
            if (abs(m_i - m_j) > 1) {
                throw std::exception("Tried to assign to a const matrix element");
            }

            return m_parent.assign(m_i, m_j, newVal);
        }
    };

    tridiagonal();
    ~tridiagonal();

    helper operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return helper(*this, i,j);
    }

    const T& operator()(int i, int j) const; 

    private:

    T& assign(int i, int j, const T &newVal);

    //holds data of just the diagonals
    T * m_upper;
    T * m_main;
    T * m_lower;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    tridiagonal<double> mat;

std::cout << mat(0,0) << std::endl;

const tridiagonal<double> & constMat = mat;

std::cout << mat(2,3) << std::endl;

// Compiles and works
mat(2,3) = 10.0;

// Compiles, but throws at runtime
mat(1, 5) = 20.0;

// Doesn't compile
// constMat(3,3) = 12.0;

    return 0;
}
```

It's been a while since I've done this, so you may find that you need to add a bit more to the helper class, depending on how you use the matrix.

Actually working through this is a good C++ exercise. :)

Answer (score 0):

Returning by reference requires that you return a valid object of the specified type. The simplest way to accomplish what you want is to keep a static `T` object that represents 0, and return it instead.

Alternatively, you could return a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra member representing some dummy value and make sure it always reads as 0.

```
template<typename T>
class tridiagonal 
{
    // usual stuff...

    T& operator() (int j, int j)
    {
        // if not explicitly stored, reset to default before returning.
        return stored(i,j)? fetch(i,j) : (m_dummy=T());
    }
private:
    // dummy element used to "reference" elements outside the 3 diagonals.
    T m_dummy;

    // check if (i,j) is on 3 diagonals.
    bool stored (int i, int j) const;

    // access element on 3 diagonals. precondition: stored(i,j)==true.
    T& fetch (int i, int j);

    //holds data of just the diagonals
    T * m_upper;
    T * m_main;
    T * m_lower;
};
```

Note that technically speaking, someone could trick you as such:

```
tridiagonal<int> m(4,4);
T * dummy = &m(3,0); // *dummy == 0.
*dummy = 1;          // *dummy == 1.
std::cout << *dummy; // prints 1.
```

But that's not necessarily a problem.